# I'm trying to remove classes like class="row" and class="col-md-12" coming from a script file from bootstrap.Can I override and remove it with css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm  trying to remove classes like  class="row" and class="col-md-12" coming from a script file from bootstrap. Can I override and remove it with css?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can remove a class from the markup with css. You could add an additional class and then make your needed style changes with that more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to hide them  by default? If so, create a rule on your css for the mentioned classes.

```
.row,  .col-md-12{
 display: none;
}
```

Then after, if you  want to show them, you can use js to present the elements with that class. Ex:

```
document.querySelector('.row').style.display= 'block';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the class names via CSS, but you can retrieve all the elements with those class names and remove the class:
`document.querySelectorAll(".row").forEach(r => r.classList.remove("row"));`